# height and widths are interchanged but app displayed in landscape mode based on android versions

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6, android-orientation, device-orientation

My mobile game android app should be in landscape mode,
when I maximize after minimize the app it will display in landscape mode and screen not rotated, but the problem is **height** and **width** are **interchanged**. So it was displayed half of the screen only remaining was **blank screen**.
If we lock and unlock the device, automatically the height and widths are fit according to screen size.

I handled the above problem using **Event.ACTIVATE**, if app is active then i reset the **width,height,scaleX and scaleY. In 4.0, 4.1, 4.2**  versions of android it is working fine but when we used **4.4, 5.1** it will shows same problem. How can we rectify this ?

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, handleActivate, false, 0, true);

private function handleActivate(event:Event):void
{
    NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;

    if ( main.mainMcProperties.width > main.mainMcProperties.height )
    {
        gametble.width = main.mainMcProperties.width;
        gametble.height = main.mainMcProperties.height;

        gametble.scaleX = main.mainMcProperties.scaleX;
        gametble.scaleY = main.mainMcProperties.scaleY;
    }
    else
    {
        gametble.width = main.mainMcProperties.height;
        gametble.height = main.mainMcProperties.width;

        gametble.scaleX = main.mainMcProperties.scaleY;
        gametble.scaleY = main.mainMcProperties.scaleX;
    }
}
```

Comment: NativeApplication.nativeApplication.addEventListener(Event.ACTIVATE, handleActivate, false, 0, true);

private function handleActivate(e:Event):void
  {
   NativeApplication.nativeApplication.systemIdleMode = SystemIdleMode.KEEP_AWAKE;
   
   gametble.scaleX = main.mainMcProp.scaleX;
   gametble.scaleY = main.mainMcProp.scaleY;
   if ( main.mainMcProp.width > main.mainMcProp.height )
   {
    gametble.width = main.mainMcProp.width;
    gametble.height = main.mainMcProp.height;
   }
   else
   {
    gametble.width = main.mainMcProp.height;
    gametble.height = main.mainMcProp.width;
   }
  }

Comment: @galath please check it once, sorry for alignment.

Comment: If you have more data in a question, you'd better edit your old question (it-ll go up in activity and will have higher chances to get answered).